# Group theory Orbits question Normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a finite group which acts transitively on $X$, and if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, show that the orbits of the induced action of $H$ on $X$ all have the same size.

Answer (score 3):

For $x \in X$, write $G_x = \{g \in G : g\cdot x = x\}$, and $H_x = \{g \in H : g\cdot x = x\}$. Note that
$$
H_x = H\cap G_x ~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$

1. If $y = g\cdot x$, then $G_y = gG_xg^{-1}$, hence
   $$
   H_y \stackrel{(1)}{=} H \cap G_y =H\cap gG_xg^{-1} \stackrel{H \unlhd G}{=} g(H\cap G_x)g^{-1} \stackrel{(1)}{=} gH_xg^{-1}
   $$
   As $g$ was fixed, we see that
   $$
   |H_y| = |H_x|~~~~~~~~(2).
   $$
2. Applying the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem yields:
   $$
   |H|=|O(y)|\cdot |H_y| = |O(x)| \cdot |H_x|.
   $$
   Combining this with (2), we get:
   $$
   |O(y)|=|O(x)|.
   $$

Since $G$ acts transitively on $X$, there's such a $g$ for every pair $x,y \in X$ and it follows that any two $H-$orbits have the same cardinality.

Comment: If y=gx, then y and g are elements of the same orbit. I don't know how to use the fact that H is normal to G. Maybe I need to use that if 2 points are in the same orbit, their stabilizers are conjugate?

Comment: Exactly. If $G_y = gG_xg^{-1}$, then how are $H_y$ and $H_x$ related?

Comment: g is an element of G, right? And H_x is the stabilizer of the element x in the subgroup H, so the subgroup H_x of H are all the h in H for which h(x)=x... The order of H_x is a divisor of the order of H, idem for the order of H_y.

Comment: @Heinz1 : I have edited my post with a complete proof.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was very clear. I just didn't get the last step. Could you please clear that a bit? How do you use the fact that G acts transitively on X? Which means that there only exists one single orbit. Is that right?

Comment: No, it means that every $y \in X$ can be written as $y = g\cdot x$

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time.

Comment: @Prahlad: why do you say no? It does mean there is only one orbit and your equation implies it as well..

Comment: @Marek : There is only one $G-$orbit. There may be more than one $H$-orbit. They are, however, of the same cardinality.